# Question wrt Binomial theorem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, combinations, binomial-theorem

This question may sound too stupid. But I am quite confused by the Binomial theorem

As per my understanding, let us consider

$(x+y)^4$ without the coefficients.

$(x+y)^4 = x^4 + x^3y + x^2y^2 + xy^3 + y^4$

Now if we take the term $x^2y^2$ as per the binomial theorem the coefficient would be 6. because ${4 \choose 2}$ gives the answer to be 6. But why do we take only $y$ term into consideration during coefficient calculation but now x term.

I feel it should be $4 \choose 2$$4 \choose 2$ both multiplied because we need to select two $x$ and two $y$. In that case the coefficient would be 36. But according to binomial theorem it is 6. Where I am going wrong?

kindly explain me

Comment: Once you selected two $x$'s, there is nothing else to select: $y$'s are forced to be in the remaining places.

Comment: @Crostul: Thank you, But they are 4 y's which are not selected, but we need only two y's out of 4 is ${4 \choose 2}$ right?

Answer (score 2):

Note that$$(x+y)^4=(x+y)\times(x+y)\times(x+y)\times(x+y).$$The coefficient of $xy$ is the number of $x^2y^2$'s that we get when we expand this product. And there are as many ways of getting a $x^2y^2$ as there are ways of picking two of the factors and using its $x$ and using the $y$ from the remaining two factors. And in how many ways can we do that? In $\binom42=6$ ways.

Comment: Did you mean $x^2y^2$?

Comment: I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: Is it now how many ways we get 2 x's and 2 y's from $x^2y^2$?

Comment: Now. It's how many ways we get two $x$'s and two $y$'s from $(x+y)\times(x+y)\times(x+y)\times(x+y).$

Comment: +1 I've always taught the binomial theorem like this, it feels like a really nice explanation - yet one day you realize that some students actually don't understand why expanding is related to the very process of selecting a summand from each factor. Sigh.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier I agree. Induction is fine for proving it, but not for understanding why it is true.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thanks for the response, one question let us say I have to only select 3 $x$'s from 10 $x$'s. The answer is still one way right? instead of ${10 \choose 3}$?

Comment: @Siddarth I don't understand your question.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Let me rephrase the question suppose I have 10 chocolates of the same type and category and I want to select 4 among them. How many ways I can select 4 chocolates is it $10 \choose 4$ or only 1 way since all the chocolates are of same type and category?

Comment: @Siddarth Since the chocolates are all equal, I'd say that there's only one way.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thanks a lot for the reply, so If I understand correctly then in $(x+y)^4$ the coefficient of $x^2y^2$ is ${4 \choose 2}$ instead of ${4 \choose 2}*{4 \choose 2}$ because once two x's are selected there is only way to select the remaining y's right?

Answer (score 0):

The  selection is symmetric in $x$ and in $y$. In order to count the number of ways to get $x^2y^2$ in
\begin{align*}
(x+y)^4=(x+y)(x+y)(x+y)(x+y)
\end{align*}
we select from each of the four binomials $x+y$ either $x$ or $y$ in total two $x$'s and two $y$'s. We have
\begin{align*}
&x\,x\,\color{blue}{y}\,\color{blue}{y}\qquad\qquad 
\color{blue}{y}\,\color{blue}{y}\,x\,x\\
&x\,\color{blue}{y}\,x\,\color{blue}{y}\qquad\qquad
\color{blue}{y}\,x\,\color{blue}{y}\,x\\
&x\,\color{blue}{y}\,\color{blue}{y}\,x\qquad\qquad
\color{blue}{y}\,x\,x\,\color{blue}{y}
\end{align*}

giving a total of $6$ possibilities.

> In fact this symmetry is also given by the definition of the binomial coefficient in terms of factorials
>   \begin{align*}
> 6=\binom{4}{2}=\frac{4!}{\color{blue}{2!2!}}=\binom{4}{\color{blue}{2,2}}
> \end{align*}
>   and also explicitly by the *[multinomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients)* notation at the right-hand side.